Change background color with gtkada css
Hi everyone and sorry again for the inconvenience but since then I have created a window with gtkada to which I want to change the color of the background with css, but this is where things get complicated for me. I can't import css into my program.
Here is my simple code :
File.ads

package file is

type abstract_type is abstract tagged null record;
Type my_window_record is new abstract_type with private;
type my_window is access all my_window_record'class;

procedure create_window (Window : my_window);

procedure open_window (window : my_window);

procedure style_window (window : my_window);

private

type my_window_record is new abstract_type with record

Win : Gtk_Window;
Provider : Gtk_Css_Provider;
Context : Gtk_Style_Context;

end record;
end file;

file.adb
package body file is

procedure create_window (window : my_window) is
begin

Gtk_New (Window.Win);
Window.Win.Fullscreen;
style_window (window);

end create_window;

procedure open_window (window : my_window ) is
begin

Window.Win.Show_All;

end open_window;

procedure style_window (window : my_window) is

      Error : aliased GError;
      Bool : aliased Boolean;
   begin
      
      Gtk_New (window.Provider);
      Gtk_New (window.Context);
      Bool := Load_From_Data (window.Provider,"style.css", Error'Access);
      Add_Provider (window.Context, + window.Provider, 0);

end style_window;

main.adb
procedure main is

win : my_window;

begin
Gtk.Main.Init;

win := new my_window_record;
create_window (Win);
open_window (Win);

Gtk.Main.Main;

end main;


When compiling everything goes well without any error messages. But the background color of the window has not changed. I would like to know why, or am I missing something?.
And here is my very simple css code :
style.css
window {
         background-color: red;
}

anyone have an idea???

what version of GtkAda do you use? CSS has changed between Gtk 3.14 (older Gtkada) and 3.24

Another idea is to use the Gtk Inspector to change the CSS on-the-fly, to see if you are able to modify the color of other UI elements, just as a test: https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tools/inspector.html#
